# XML Preview looks different than in device

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

As written in the topic, I have an android App, which has a design - that design is being shown differently on my Phone than in the XML-Preview.

Screenshots:
[image: In Android Studio]
[image: In My Device]

As you can see on my device, the button at the bottom is far more in the top than it should be. Any fixes?

Comment: because the screen size is bigger on the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the screen size. If you are just stacking the views in a LinearLayout they will take up whatever room they need and the the bottom will be blank. If you want you can make the button be pushed to the bottom by using `layout_weight=1` on whichever view you want to take up the remaining space.

Comment: changing the ScrollView layout_weight to 1 indeed fixed it.